# Select Bits in 4-to -1 MUX

Tags: multiplexer

Can there be 3 select bits in a 4to1 MUX?

I needed it for a particular application and have no alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have that. You'll just have some selection combinations that make the same selection. For instance:

```
module mux_4to1(Y, A, B, C, D, sel);

output [15:0] Y;
input [15:0] A, B, C, D;
input [2:0] sel;
reg [15:0] Y;
always @(A or B or C or D or sel)
  case ( sel )
    3'b000: Y = A;
    3'b001: Y = A;
    3'b010: Y = B;
    3'b011: Y = B;
    3'b100: Y = C;
    3'b101: Y = C;
    3'b110: Y = D;
    3'b111: Y = D;
    default: Y = 16'hxxxx;
  endcase
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 MUXes with both enable and inhibit inputs, then you can connect the third bit to the enable input of one and the inhibit input of the other, expanding them into a 8-input MUX.